# Numpy functions clobber my inherited datatype

Tags: python, numpy, inheritance

Say I have a class `ndarray_plus` that inherits from `numpy.ndarray` and adds some extra functionality. Sometimes I pass it to numpy functions like `np.sum` and get back an object of type `ndarray_plus`, as expected.

Other times, numpy functions that I pass my enhanced object to return  an `numpy.ndarray` object, destroying the information in the extra `ndarray_plus` attributes. This happens usually when the numpy function in question does a `np.asarray` instead of `np.asanyarray`.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I can't go into the numpy codebase and change all instances of `np.asarray` to `np.asanyarray`. Is there a Pythonic way to pre-emptively protect my inherited object?

Comment: A subclass like `np.matrix` has a lot of code dedicated to maintaining the class and attributes.  Same for `np.ma`. That is part of why subclassing `ndarray` is not a trivial task.  I'd suggest studying those examples.

Comment: Ok, second attempt. Since what you observe is the defined behaviour of `np.asarray` it's hard to see what you could do. You could try and monkey-patch `asarray` with `asanarray` if it works and is compatible with your standards of Pythonicity.

Comment: @hpaulj as I read it once your subclass falls into the claws of `asarray` it's finished, `matrix` certainly is.

Comment: In such a case the subclass may need to define its own method.  It may help to name some specific functions or methods that give problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defined and guaranteed behaviour of `asarray` is to convert your subclass instance back to base class

```
help on function asarray in numpy:

numpy.asarray = asarray(a, dtype=None, order=None)
Convert the input to an array.

Parameters
----------
a : array_like
    Input data, in any form that can be converted to an array.  This
    includes lists, lists of tuples, tuples, tuples of tuples, tuples
    of lists and ndarrays.
dtype : data-type, optional
    By default, the data-type is inferred from the input data.
order : {'C', 'F'}, optional
    Whether to use row-major (C-style) or
    column-major (Fortran-style) memory representation.
    Defaults to 'C'.

Returns
-------
out : ndarray
    Array interpretation of `a`.  No copy is performed if the input
    is already an ndarray.  If `a` is a subclass of ndarray, a base
    class ndarray is returned.

See Also
--------
asanyarray : Similar function which passes through subclasses.
```

< - snip - >

You could try and monkeypatch:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import mpt
>>> 
>>> s = np.matrix(3)
>>> mpt.aa(s)
array([[3]])
>>> np.asarray = np.asanyarray
>>> mpt.aa(s)
matrix([[3]])
```

file `mpt.py`

```
import numpy as np

def aa(x):
   return np.asarray(x)
```

Sadly, this doesn't always work.

alternative `mpt.py`

```
from numpy import asarray

def aa(x):
   return asarray(x)
```

here you'd be out of luck.

Comment: I don't think it is wise to change `asarray`.  Let it remain as a way of converting `self` to the base class.  `apply_over_axes` is a function that uses `asarray`.  `np.ma.apply_over_axes` retains the use of `asarray.  It replaces `expand_dims` with its own version.  `np.ma.average` is another example.  `np.matrix` uses `asarray` to return its `.A` and `.A1` properties.

Comment: @hpaulj agreed. But I also tend to agree with the OP that its use in library functions which don't really need to convert should be regarded as a bug.

Comment: @hpaulj perhaps one could try and use `__array_prepare__` to switch `asarray` to `asanyarray` and the reinstate it in `__array_wrap__` to contain the side effects?